# How to choose channel in m3u8 with video.js

Tags: video.js, channel, playlist, m3u8

I am using video.js to play m3u8 and this file contains multiple channels.
I would like to show channel list and choose any of them to play.
I have searched but I couldn't find this function.
This is source code

```
<video-js id="my_video_1" class="vjs-default-skin" controls preload="auto" width="640" height="268">
    <source src="--m3u8 file path--" type="application/x-mpegURL">
  </video-js>

  <script src="https://unpkg.com/video.js/dist/video.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/@videojs/http-streaming/dist/videojs-http-streaming.js"></script>

  <script>
    var player = videojs('my_video_1');

  </script>
```

This is my m3u8 file content

```
#EXTM3U 
#EXTINF:0,##### |AR| MOROCCO ##### 
line.ma-cobra.com:80/Cesar2/Y5SNvNqGfyxH3Qb/3547 
#EXTINF:0,|AR| CORONA VIRUS INFO 
line.ma-cobra.com:80/Cesar2/Y5SNvNqGfyxH3Qb/113221 
#EXTINF:0,|AR| AL AOULA INTER 
line.ma-cobra.com:80/Cesar2/Y5SNvNqGfyxH3Qb/2189
```

Now there are 3 urls (which I call channel, I don't know if it's correct to call this channel) So I want to show menu of containing these 3 links and want to click one to see it. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by “channels”? There is no such concept in HLS. Do your mean variants, or renditions?

Comment: Please don’t post new information into comments. Update the question.

Comment: I have updated question

Answer (score 2):

this is the documentation [video.js](https://unpkg.com/browse/@videojs/http-streaming@1.2.5/README.md). I think what you are looking for, is to change the source of the video. When you create an instance you can change the source with any event.

```
var player = videojs('some-video-id');

player.src({
  src: 'https://link.to./file.m3u8',
  type: 'application/x-mpegURL',
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are combining different pieces of content inside the same HLS master manifest. Master manifests are supposed to contain different renditions of the same content, such as different quality levels or alternate audio. @joshua-joel-cleveland is correct. You would need to change the src value for your video element when you want to change content/channels.